# Android unable to switch to front camera in surface view

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I have tried to open front camera in surface view, but i got the result  **Fail to connect to camera service**

**Tried Code**

```
    mCamera= Camera.open(cameraId);
```

**0 for CAMERA_FACING_BACK**

**1 for CAMERA_FACING_FRONT**

What is the solution..?

Comment: specific the error, what is it?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I got the answer

```
    reverseCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean hasFront = hasFrontCamera();
            if (hasFront) {
                reverseCamera.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                mCamera.release();

                if (currentCameraId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                    currentCameraId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
                } else {
                    currentCameraId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
                }
                mCamera = Camera.open(currentCameraId);

                setCameraDisplayOrientation(MainActivity.this, currentCameraId, mCamera);
                try {

                    mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mCamera.startPreview();
            } else {
                reverseCamera.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

    });

    public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
                                               int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
    android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
            new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
    android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
            .getRotation();
    int degrees = 0;
    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            degrees = 0;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            degrees = 90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            degrees = 180;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            degrees = 270;
            break;
    }

    int result;
    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
    } else {  // back-facing
        result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you attach your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Maybe you forgot add permission for use camera.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

More info, you can take [camera class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html)

Comment: after that i have the same error **java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service**